# Using a Yahama electric piano with Kubuntu (18.04)

Tags: kubuntu, midi

I have a Yamaha electric piano connected to my laptop, which is running Kubuntu 18.04.   **lsusb** confirms that the computer indeed sees the piano.  But I still understand how to perform two basic tasks: playing a midi file on the piano and capturing keyboard input on the computer.  I've downloaded a plethora of related software but it hasn't helped so far.  Where can I find enlightenment?

Comment: Does `aplaymidi -l` show the piano?

Comment: It shows Portable Grand Midi 1, which I assume is the Yamaha.

Comment: Do `aplaymidi -p x:y something.mid` and `aseqdump -p x:y` work? If yes, then any other programs should work as well, if configured correctly.

Comment: OK, at last I've actually managed to play a midi file -- I can hear it!!! But I had to specify the midi port explicitly.  Is there a way to create a default for the midi port?

Comment: There is a mechanism for `aplaymidi`, but it would not apply to other programs. What software do you actually want to use?

Comment: For the time being, aplaymidi will suffice.  Eventually I'd like to be able to use midisheetmusic.

Comment: The midisheetmusic web site says that it uses Timidity++, a software synthesizer. I do not know if actually supports playing to a 'real' MIDI port. Anyway, `aplaymidi` reads the `ALSA_OUTPUT_PORTS` environment variable, but you could just as well create an alias in your shell, or write a wrapper script.